# App is crashing but there is no error in the code

Tags: java, android

I am getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` in the error log and after that app is crashed. I am not getting any error in my java code. I am not sure which library is causing this issue. Your help is highly appreciated.

I have updated few libraries to **28** and to **27** but still getting the same error.

**Error**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getScreenWidthDp(Landroid/content/res/Resources;)I in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ConfigurationHelper; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ConfigurationHelper' appears in /data/app/com
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.test"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.szagurskii:patternedtextwatcher:0.5.0'
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'

}
```

If I update the appcompat to 28 then I am getting below error.

```
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'


 * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$1
```

Comment: You **shouldn't mix** different versions like 27 and 28, you will end up having strange error, trust me.

Comment: I am still getting error if I update it to 28.

Comment: Logcat is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

Without the full stacktrace it is impossible to tell where the error originates. The only thing that looks suspicious in your build file is that you don't have a common android support version. You use libraries of both the `27.0.0` and `28.0.0` versions.

Comment: most likely that's the issue, change your appcompat v7 to 28 and rebuild

Comment: If I update the version to 28 then I am getting below error. * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$1

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I have updated my post with log.

Comment: Try to clean the project after updating the dependencies, and check if you still get the same error message Build -> Clean Project

Comment: If you have the same error while building though a terminal/cmd then it's not a Android Studio isssue. @JuanHurtado is right, Android Studio can have some cache issues. There are two or three cache folder to delete if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

After adding  implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0' then this issue got resolved. Thanks everyone for your comments.

Comment: Mark this a approved